# c++, reading files, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, file, io, segmentation-fault

I was working on this function read. The `main` I used has no problem in file I/O, it connects fine, closes, the files are okay too. However, I am getting a segmentation fault by the end of the reading. I have tried printing out for testing, and the error is reading the last line. It finishes reading the last line for string `a`, and then `x`, and then `in.good()` becomes false too. I have tried resetting `in.clear()`, also, setting the string `a="";` if `in.good` becomes false. Nothing is working.

```
read(istream& in){
    string a;
    int x;
    in>>a;
    while( in.good() ){
        in>>x;
        char *ch;
        strcpy( ch, a.c_str() );
        Word cwd(ch);
        anObject.add(cwd,x);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Which bit has been set? `badbit, eofbit or failbit`? That will probably give you a good idea what you need to look at next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see a segfault because you're not allocating space for `ch`, and then you're attempting to copy a string over it. `ch` is an uninitialized memory address that doesn't belong to you.

You'll need to allocate space for the string:

```
char *ch = new[(MAX_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(char)];
```

But why is it that you need a `char *` here? Note that you can always pass around `a` and use `a.c_str()` if you must have a C string. I'm not sure what `Word` is, or if it needs it's own copy of a string, but can you use: `Word cwd(a.c_str())`?

Comment: If I catch anyone using `malloc` in a C++ program, I'll beat them to death with their own program listings :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to create this Word class in the last assignment in school, but didn't have necessary constructors for strings or can't use a.c_str() directly for that function returns const char* that my Word class don't have.

Comment: Agree with @paxdiablo use new not malloc

Comment: @pb2q cool - weird things happen when you mix them - very hard to debug :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish sure thing, I avoid mixing in actual code, but when posting answers I sometimes don't filter. But this is **mostly** a C++ question

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't allocate memory storage for `char *ch`. The moment you define this variable, it is a random value on the stack. Writing a random memory will corrupt the memory and cause seg fault when cleanup the memory(both manually or automatically at function return).